# Do all Ubuntu users get the same patches as Ubuntu Advantage users?

Tags: canonical, patch

Does Ubuntu provide the same patches to normal users as it does to Canonical Advantage users, or is it like Red Hat where if you pay for support you get patches faster?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> where if you pay for support you get patches faster?

For systems that are not end of life there is no difference.

> Does Ubuntu provide the same patches to normal users

For systems that are not end of life there is no difference.

Ubuntu Advantage users get the following perks ...

- Extended Security Maintenance (ESM)
- Kernel live patch service to avoid reboots
- Landscape on-premises systems management tool
- 24/7 phone and ticket support
- Support for OpenStack, Kubernetes, Ceph/Swift and more
- Knowledge base access
- IP legal assurance program
- FIPS 140-2 certified crypto modules and Common Criteria

The 1st one is the one that matters:

> **Security and compliance**
>
> Aligning to organisational needs to build upon rapid release cycles, ESM ensures systems and the Linux kernel remain patched against security vulnerabilities through Ubuntu Advantage.
>
> Canonical’s Ubuntu security team provide fixes on high and critical CVEs (common vulnerabilities and exposures) for the most commonly used server packages in the Ubuntu main archive. ESM provides the essential continuation of the security updates for 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) and 14.04 LTS (Trusty Tahr) that Ubuntu users have always received via a secure, private archive.

it means Advantage offers support beyond end of life. So where 12.04 is not being updated, Ubuntu Advantage will provide security updates. Mind that we also get these updates but that is because we do not use 12.04 anymore.